# Prevent export internal types from typescript npm package without external tools such as rollup

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have an npm package in typescript with package json defined like so:

```
{
  "name": "@whatever/mypackage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types":"index.d.ts",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "postbuild": "cpy './src/somefiles/*.data' './dist/somefiles/' && cpy package.json ./dist",
    "my-publish": "npm run build && npm publish ./dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cpy-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "^4.7.8"
  }
}
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "es2021",
      "declaration": true,
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "noImplicitReturns": false,
      "strictNullChecks": false,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "removeComments": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
    },
    "lib": ["es6"]
  }
```

I then have some folders and files in my package like so:

```
|
| somefiles
            |
            | somedata.data
            | somedata.ts
            | somefiles.ts
| index.ts
| basefile.ts
```

In my `somefiles.ts` I have the following code

```
import { SomeDataModel, SomeDataDescriptor } from "./somedata";

export enum SomeFiles {
    SomeData
}

export { SomeDataModel, SomeDataDescriptor };
```

And finally in my `somedata.ts`

```
import { BaseFile } from "../basefile";
import { SomeFiles } from "somefiles";

export interface SomeDataModel {
    name: string;
}

export class SomeDataDescriptor implements BaseFile {
    constructor(model: SomeDataModel) {
        this.type = SomeFiles.SomeData;
        this.model = model;
    }
    
    model: any;
    type: SomeFiles;
}
```

Now when I install this package as a dependency I can import both

```
import { SomeDataDescriptor } from '@whatever/mypackage/somefiles/somefiles';
```

OR I can

```
import  { SomeDataDescriptor } from '@whatever/mypackage/somefiles/somedata';
```

How can I prevent the ability for the consuming app to import the type from the SECOND location?

Essentially I want all my types to be imported from `somefiles/somefiles` as a barrel file.

I found some articles online but they all talk about some third party bundlers, I am hoping to achieve this simply with `tsc` and `npm` commands